# Site doesn't work when updating to SSL using nginx

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multi-language, nginx, plugin-wpml

What works:

```
https://www.exampleBE.be
http://www.exampleFR.fr
```

What doesn't work:

```
https://www.exampleFR.fr ( ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome )
```

I'm using EasyEngine for my nginx configuration and had a successfull update for --letsencrypt ( requesting SSL). This means the IP is correct and the domain mapping in nginx is also correct.

What doesn't work, is that https seems to rejected and http seems to be accessible. But i don't know why.

I used a trick to support multi domains on EasyEngine:

```
http://community.rtcamp.com/t/how-to-add-a-subdomain-or-mapped-domain-to-a-ms-installation-secured-with-lets-encrypt/7082
```

Basicly, i create a ee site with exampleBE.be and exampleFR.fr , but in the nginx configuration for exampleFR.fr i point the htdocs to exampleBE.be instead of exampleFR.fr

Answer (score 0):

Fault was with the dns of the ISP provider. It was still cached from a server migration. Where the http was configured on Apache ( old server)